# ng-bind filter value from another list of hashes

Tags: angularjs

```
$scope.myid = '1';
$scope.all = [{id: '1', name: 'one'},
              {id: '2', name: 'two'},
              {id: '3', name: 'three'}];
```

For display purposes, I would like to display the name of the selected id. The following only displays `[object Object]`:

```
<span ng-bind="all | filter: {id: myid}"><span>
```

It also gives digest warnings:

```
10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!
```

How can I bind my selected id, but display its name instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is the most appropriate use of `filter`. It's really used to get subsets of arrays.

You can have a method that will get the object with the specific id:

```
<span ng-bind="getObjectWithId(all, myid).name"></span>
```

Controller:

```
function AppController ($scope) {
    $scope.myid = '1';
    $scope.all = [{id: '1', name: 'one'},
        {id: '2', name: 'two'},
        {id: '3', name: 'three'}];

    $scope.getObjectWithId = function(array, id) {
        var match = null;
        angular.forEach(array, function(object, index) {
            if (object.id === id) {
                match = object;
            }
        });
        return match;
    }
}

angular
    .module('ModuleName', [])
    .controller('AppController', ['$scope', AppController]);
```

It essentially boils down to:

```
<span ng-bind="selectedObject.name"></span>
```